# REST - Can internet caches be used with access-token protected resources?

Tags: security, rest, caching

Can RESTful applications, like Facebook, which require an access token in order to view a certain resource use an internet-HTTP-caching system?

Can the application rely on such caches, or it needs to write its own application-security-regarding-cache system?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The caching layer would need to perform authentication, which can be done but isn't the norm.